# VIBER. Как получить ссылку на картинку

Tags: java, viber, viber-api

Подскажите как получить ссылку на картинку при отправке через чат бот картинки для пользователя. 
По документации, создаем обьект

```
{  
"receiver":"01234567890A=",
  "min_api_version":1,
  "sender":{  
  "name":"John McClane",
  "avatar":"http://avatar.example.com"
  },
  "tracking_data":"tracking data",
  "type":"picture",
  "text":"Photo description",
  "media":"http://www.images.com/img.jpg",
  "thumbnail":"http://www.images.com/thumb.jpg"
}
```

а где/как взять ссылку "media":"..."?

Comment: В смысле где взять :) Это же URL картинки которую вы собираетесь послать получателю... Берете любую картинку лОжите ее на какой-нибудь сетевой ресурс, путь на нее указываете в поле `media`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В смысле где взять :) Это же URL картинки которую вы собираетесь послать получателю... Берете любую картинку лОжите ее на какой-нибудь сетевой ресурс, путь на нее указываете в поле `media`

Например, если хотите послать свою аватарку с умным видом в очечках:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то URL будет такой:

```
 "media":"https://i.stack.imgur.com/QatwZ.jpg?s=328&g=1"
```

Comment: я накануне реализовывал телеграмм, там телега принимает себе и возвращает линк на картинку, а потом можно уже отправлять юзеру линк через апи телеги. А тут эвокак))